# AWS Autoscaling: query tags from all related EC2s

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli, aws-auto-scaling

I have several EC2 under the same Autoscaling Group, and each of them has a tag named "TheKey" with different values.
Now I need to collect all the values from those keys (no matter which value is on which EC2).

Is there a direct query I can do without first asking the ASG for the list of instances and then loop through all of them to get the tag?

Comment: What would you want the "direct query" to do? You could use `DescribeInstances()` to list _all_ EC2 instances and view the tags. Would that satisfy your needs?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein, if I could filter by ASG, it could be great!

Comment: When using `DescribeInstances()` you can filter by tag. All instances in an Auto Scaling group are assigned by tag, so you could use that to filter the list. Take a look at an instance to see that tags that Auto Scaling has assigned to them.